# Does not Retrieve the info when requested although the parameter is set already

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to add review part for a restaurant page, I have used hidden_fiedd to pass the `restauran_id` to the `review#new` page, but when I submit the review, it doesn't assign the `restaurant_id` to review and it is causing problems.

in `create` action in `reviews_controller` I have: `@review = Review.new`.

```
Parameters: {"review"=>{"score"=>"", "email"=>"", "restaurant_id"=>"471746462", 
"first_name"=>"", "content"=>"", "last_name"=>""}, 
"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Post Review",
"authenticity_token"=>"JzCoTOWj7k2huy9GTRknz+hU4Ej/Gg+dHEHvoz2vtcA="}
```

but when I try to get restaurant from the parameter, it says nil.

```
@restaurant = Restaurant.find_by_id(@review.restaurant_id)
```

or

```
@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
```

Query:

```
SELECT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" WHERE "restaurants"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[review][:restaurant_id])
```

Instead of :

```
@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
```

If you check the params hash, you will see that `restaurant_id` is a nested parameter inside `review`.